# Excel IF Function Query - Dates

Tags: arrays, excel, function, if-statement, spreadsheet

I am looking for some help regarding an IF function on an Excel document.

Basically if the Date Listed cell is dated over 1 month ago (eg: Date Listed 6-Aug but today is 6-Sep) and the Date Sold cell is blank, then I would like the Mark Down cell to say 'MARK DOWN', which at the moment it does but it is only 10-Aug today.

If the Date Listed cell and the Date Sold cell both contain dates I would like the Mark Down cell to say 'OK'.

So far I have this written:

```
=IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(G2),MONTH(G2),DAY(G2)), ISBLANK(H2)),"MARK DOWN","OK")
```

I know I'm not far off but I need help sorting out the last parts..

Bonus if you can help me add a highlighted cell formatting to it :)!

[EXAMPLE IMAGE]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

```
IF(AND((TODAY()-g2)>31,ISBLANK(H2)),"Mark Down","OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply conditional formatting on all the cells in MARK DOWN column which are equal to OK.

[image]

After that write this simple formula to check the condition.

> =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(G2),ISNUMBER(H2)),"OK","MARK DOWN")

Comment: I think you are missing the date check in your formula as per OP's request

Comment: @Zac If OP enters date in date format then this should work as date should be essentially a number and I doubt if OP will enter anything else in it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point here but as I understood OP's query, the `Mark Down` check is if the date is over a month old + the blank cell. Your formula checks if it's a number but I don't see where it's performing the date validation

Answer (score 0):

Update: if you use EDATE function everything gets simplified as this function takes care of exact day differences
so the whole solution is :

=IF(AND(EDATE((G2),1)=EDATE(NOW(),0),ISBLANK(H2)),"MarkDown","")

Let me know if you have any question on how this formula works.